# Should I still use the keyword explicit for copy constructors?

Tags: c++11, software-design, explicit, explicit-conversion

> C++ provides the keyword explicit to suppress implicit conversions via
>   conversion constructors when such conversions should not be allowed. A
>   constructor that's declared explicit cannot be used in an implicit
>   conversion. Use the explicit keyword on single-argument constructors
>   that should not be used by the compiler to perform implicit
>   conversions.

This makes sense, BUT should I still use the keyword explicit for copy constructors? In what other cases would it be useful to use the keyword explicit and why?

Comment: Please cite your quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's legal to declare a copy constructor explicit. Declaring it or not really depends on what you want to do. For example, you declare a copy constructor `explicit` if you want to forbid it from being called implicitly at function calls or with the copy-initialization syntax.

Comment: It's legal but generally silly. Such a type isn't CopyConstructible.